# VLC does't send OPTIONS and DESCRIBE requests during RTSP

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I made a simple RTSP server that streams video and audio.
In previous versions of VLC everything was ok both the video and audio streams were playing well.
In the last version of VLC when I'm trying to play RTSP stream with the very same request addres I'm getting nothing.

Looking at the logs of my server I keep seeing that VLC is not sending the OPTIONS and DESCRIBE requests so my server can't send the sdp file back.
VLC jumps stright at the SETUP request without any information about what exactly my server should setup.

```
SETUP rtsp://192.168.0.1:514 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 0
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=9030-9031
```

Also the VLC options that enforced interleaved rtsp through tcp is gone in the new version. I needed this too.

VLC version I'm currently using 3.0.16 Vetinari and my OS is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Thank you

Comment: Im seeing this too. Its very confusing because the RTSP spec seems pretty clear about what should occur here and VLC has a great reputation, so why is it skipping steps in the spec?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: install the `live-media` package (`liblivemedia` on Ubuntu).

I had the same issue and found the solution while digging through the VLC source code. This behaviour happens when the optional RTSP dependency `live-media` is not installed. This library is loaded by the 'live555' module of VLC. When it is not found, VLC falls back to another module for RTSP which indeed does not send `OPTIONS` or `DESCRIBE`. (I don't know if that is a bug or not)

To verify if it works, run your VLC command with `-vvvv`. Search the standard output for 'live555': before this fix, it should report that it was not able to find liblivemedia and after this fix that warning should be gone.